# Setting up pragma omp on windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have this code for a parallel sum of values, but I'm stuck in the right configure of openMP. The code above works on Ubuntu with gcc, but on Windows (mingw) it's getting crazy result values. Nevertheless, it works when I run single thread, so I think it may be a wrong set. I would like some clues on how to set up correctly the pragma omp for this case.

Basically, each thread calculates and sum values to the partialsum.

```
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(subsetTemp) reduction (+:partialsum)
for(int j = 0; j < repetitions; j++){
    random_shuffle(SortOrder.begin(),SortOrder.end());

    for (unsigned int i1 = 0; i1 < subsetTemp.size(); i1++)
        for(unsigned int j1 = 0; j1 < subsetTemp[0].size(); j1++)
            subsetTemp[i1][j1]=0;

    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < currentsize; i1++){
        for(unsigned int j1 = 0; j1 < sequences[0].size(); j1++){
            subsetTemp[j1][freqmatrixposition(sequences[SortOrder[i1]][j1])]++;
            subsetTemp[sequences[0].size()][freqmatrixposition(sequences[SortOrder[i1]][j1])]++;
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < populatedpos.size() - 1; k++){
        for(unsigned int l = 0; l <= 20; l++){
            double subsetfreq = (double)subsetTemp[k][l]/(double)currentsize;
            if(subsetfreq > 0){
                if(subsetfreq* log(subsetfreq) < 0) partialsum += (subsetfreq* log(subsetfreq) * -1);
                else partialsum += (subsetfreq* log(subsetfreq));
            }
        }
    }
}
outputVec.push_back((float)(partialsum/((long double)(populatedpos.size()*repetitions))));
```

Thanks

**EDIT**
About the output, this code runs 100 times varying the currentSize, each run add a value to the outputVec. When I plot outputVec ran in multithread, looks like it has noise.

[Single thread graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJcMf.png)

[Multi thread graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgW4k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. The mainly problem was with SortOrder. It should be randomized for each iteraction, but as it used to be a class variable, many threads was accessing the same list, causing bias to the results.